# Restcomm JSS7 showing unanticipated results for the commands found in the user manual

Tags: shell, command-line-interface, restcomm, mobicents, ss7

I am trying to use Restcomm JSS7 CLI Shell tool, and I am facing a lot of trouble. I am following the Restcomm JSS7 user Manual.  According to the [section titled **`4.4. Running the Shell'Shell'`**](http://documentation.telestax.com/core/ss7/SS7_Stack_User_Guide.html#_running_shell),

> The ss7-cli   script supports the following options
>
> ```
> Usage: SS7 [OPTIONS]
> Valid Options
> -v           Display version number and exit
> -h           This help screen
> ```

But when I enter **`SS7 -v`** or **`SS7 -h`** in the shell tool, I
get errors like **`Unexpected command "SS7 -v"`** and **`Unexpected
command "SS7 -h"`** respectively.

**Why is that? What am I doing wrong?**

---

Again according to [the manual](http://documentation.telestax.com/core/ss7/SS7_Stack_User_Guide.html#_connect_shell):

> 4.4.2. Connect to Managed Instance
>
> Shell needs to connect to managed instance. Command to connect has
>   following structure:
>
> ```
>  connect <IP> <PORT>
> ```
>
> Example 1.
>
> ```
>  Connect to remote machine
>
>  mobicents>connect 10.65.208.215 3435
>
>  mobicents(10.65.208.215:3435)
> ```
>
> Host IP and port are optional, if not specified, shell will try to  connect to 127.0.0.1:3435

When I simply write connect, it successly connects, and I get
prompted to enter the username and password for authentication. But
    when I enter my machine's IP address, say it's `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`, or
    the IP address of another remote machine, like `connect 192.XXX.XXX.XXX:3435`

*Note: I have also tried to change the port to `2905`. Same result.*

I get the error viz. **`Connection refused`**, and no further information. So I want to ask two things:

- **Why I am getting this error?**
- **Where can I find further diagnostic information so that I can find out why this error is occurring so that I can take some steps to
  resolve it.**

Answer (score 0):

This part

> The ss7-cli   script supports the following options
>
> ```
> Usage: SS7 [OPTIONS]
> Valid Options
> -v           Display version number and exit
> -h           This help screen
> ```

refers to command-line options for the ss7-cli script, eg:

```
./ss7-cli -v
```

---

Are you trying to connect to a machine remotely? It needs to connect to port `3435` and by default it binds address `${jboss.bind.address}` which I think is just `127.0.0.1`, so you won't be able to connect to a different IP than localhost unless you re-configure this.

You can verify this with like `netstat -an | grep 3435` to see what address is bound. Firewall configuration on the server itself might also be an issue.

Keep in mind changing the bind address might not be a good idea for security. It would be best to run `ss7-cli` on the server itself and connect to `127.0.0.1`.